# Qt5.10 Windows: 'glVertexAttrib2fv' was not declared in this scope?

Tags: qt, opengl

I am trying to port my OpenGL project from GLFW to Qt 5.10.1 on Windows using MinGW but I am facing some issues. Everything was working perfectly until I needed to use glVertexAttrib2fv which Qt says "was not declared in this scope"! I don't know what am I missing.

main.cpp

```
QSurfaceFormat format;
format.setVersion(4, 3);
format.setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::CoreProfile);
format.setDepthBufferSize(24);
format.setStencilBufferSize(8);
format.setSamples(10); 
QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat(format);
```

myopenglwidget.h:

```
#include <QWidget>
#include <QOpenGLWidget>
#include <QOpenGLFunctions_4_3_Core>
#include <QOpenGLShaderProgram>

class MyOpenGLWidget : public QOpenGLWidget, protected QOpenGLFunctions_4_3_Core
{
protected:
    void initializeGL();
...
}

void MyOpenGLWidget::initializeGL()
{
    // initialize OpenGL Functions
    initializeOpenGLFunctions();
...
}
```

Note: glVertexAttrib2fv is supported in all versions of OpenGL: https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttrib.xhtml

Ask If more information is needed to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, the trick was to use `CompatibilityProfile` rather than `CoreProfile`!

main.cpp

```
QSurfaceFormat format;
format.setVersion(4, 3);
format.setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::CompatibilityProfile);
format.setDepthBufferSize(24);
format.setStencilBufferSize(8);
format.setSamples(10); 
QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat(format);
```

myopenglwidget.h:

```
#include <QWidget>
#include <QOpenGLWidget>
#include <QOpenGLFunctions_4_3_Compatibility>
#include <QOpenGLShaderProgram>

class MyOpenGLWidget : public QOpenGLWidget, protected QOpenGLFunctions_4_3_Compatibility
{
...
}
```

OR you can simply use `protected QOpenGLExtraFunctions`.